# Knowing side of the bed of someone

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, expressions

I listened to an English podcast that a boy asked a girl to be his friend.
here is the conversation:

> I know you better than anyone, I know
>   the pros and cons of your personality, I even know
>   ***what side of the bed is yours!*** I think we would be
>   great together, don’t you?

in this dialog, what is the meanig of expression: *i know what side of the bed is yours!*

what is the proper usecase of this expression?

Comment: In countries where English is the first language, it is common for people living together either as husband and wife or as unmarried lovers to sleep in the same bed, and for one or the other or both of them to have a preferred side of the bed.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  Thanks! does that matter what side of the bed they sleep? :)

Comment: It matters to them :)

Comment: It also implies that they respect each others space (not trying to control or tell the other person what to door how to behave.

Comment: It also implies that they have slept together at least once.

Comment: @marcellothearcane, but perhaps only in the literal sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In countries where English is the first language, it is common for people living together either as husband and wife or as unmarried lovers to sleep in the same bed, and for one or the other or both of them to have a preferred side of the bed. – Tᴚoɯɐuo

But this fact is not normally shared with people outside the relationship. The preferred side of the bed, therefore, is intimate knowledge that would the boy is using to represent his closeness to the girl. He already knows everything about her, so he knows that they would be good together. "It also implies that they respect each other's space - user3169."